# Weird Symbols Appearing on Page linked with awesome font Icon

Tags: instagram, symbols, squarespace

I have recently used the awesome font icon codes to replace text in a navigation link on my sqaurespace site. The icon appears fine however i get this weird " /> symbols appear at the start and end of the page linked with the awesome font icon. Also the code of the awesome font icon (instagram) appears on the tab on which my website is open instead of the icon or simply the text. I am using Safari. Could really use some help with this especially with my practically non-existent knowledge of coding. Appreciate any ideas you might have!

Thanks!

Stephanie

Comment: It's for sure an HTML syntax error (like if you included some code in the middle of another). Try [validating](http://validator.w3.org/) your page and it will help you to find where you have those stray symbols.

Comment: Hi JFK,

Thanks for your help! Oh so that will help me find out where the error in my code is? But it's strange because I followed the exact instructions on font awesome.

Comment: Yes, it will help. I think you made an unintentional mistake and placed some code where you shouldn't. Those symbols you see `" />` are like the end of am HTML tag like in `<img src="{image}" alt="something" />` ... so maybe you inserted something inside the structure of a similar tag and left strayed the self-closing end of the tag.